# Laravel Logout dropdown not showing after adding Bootstrap

Tags: laravel, logout

After adding Bootstrap in my layout **app.blade.php**,the default logout dropdown option is not showing.I add the Bootstrap MaxCDN from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_get_started.asp).How to fix it?
my laravel version is **5.7.21** 
And my app.blade.php holds everything default,i just add Bootstrap MaxCDN in the head tag.

```
<!-- CSRF Token -->
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

<title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>
<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" ></script>
<!-- Fonts -->
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- Styles -->
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">


        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- jQuery library -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Popper JS -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please post your html and the scripts/styles you included. We can't help you if you don't show us your code

Comment: We will need a few more details than that. Like @Jerodev said, please provide your HTML where the dropdown is placed. Are you getting any errors in the browser console?

Comment: why do you need to add bootstrap, Laravel 5.7 is coming with bootstrap 4.1 so you don't need to add it personally. But if you try to add different version of bootstrap, then you need to delete those `app.js` and `app.css` because those are taking laravel's bootstrap(which is 4.1)... and you are adding bootstrap 4.2 cdn...

Comment: and one more thing. if it doesn't work after deleting app.css and app.css. it means laravel's navigation using bootstrap 4.1 template... So you need to add new template which is from 4.2...

Comment: Thanks @Barbie. Its working fine after deleting app.js and app.css. You just give the exact answer what i was looking for.Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, i post it as an answer, you can check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to delete laravel's bootstrap links (app.css and app.js) from layout.blade